# how to run background php process in linux and end it?

Tags: php, linux, shell, ps

that's a very simple question
I have a crawler php script.

When I run a sh script:

```
php crawler.php
php crawler.php
```

It is synchronous: it wait until first php is ended to start another one.

When trying:

```
php crawler.php &
php crawler.php &
```

That looks ok, Porblem is: they do remain in processes:

```
ps - a | grep php
 8689 pts/3    00:00:00 php
 8747 pts/3    00:00:00 php
```

and the goal would be to have a cron that lucnhes 10 php scripts in background.

so once a php script has finished, it is not in processes any more, so another can be lunched.

Any clue ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

use `php crawler.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &`

Comment: why php crawler.php & does not work ?
And why do you use 2 /dev/null ?